# iOS supported architectures issue

Tags: ios, xcode, armv7

I'm having a big issue right now and I don't know why! Uploaded my app to itunesconnect and it looks that my app is only supporting arm64 architecture.
[image]

although it should also support armv7

[image]

Required device capabilities is also set to armv7. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know iOS per se, but I've seen many versions of this question and I'm guessing "build active architecture only" does exactly what it says on the tin ;)

Comment: oh thank you!!! its a duplicate